# Using a column of one DataFrame in a function - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a DataFrame which has a column with unique IDs. That same ID is used elsewhere for functions I use. I have no problem using one of the individual IDs in my function, however, I would like to use a subset of those IDs in the function and then append that to a new DataFrame.

This is what my base DataFrame looks like:

```
First_Df

+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
|   |  Unique ID |      A      |      B      |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1 | 123456     | xxxxx       | aaaaa       |
| 2 | 234567     | yyyyy       | bbbbb       |
| 3 | 345678     | zzzzz       | ccccc       |
| 4 | 456789     | uuuuu       | ddddd       |
| 5 | 567890     | vvvvv       | eeeee       |
| 6 | 678901     | wwwww       | fffff       |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I have a subset of those values in a separate DatFrame like so:

```
Subset_Df

+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
|   |  Unique ID |      A      |      B      |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2 | 234567     | yyyyy       | bbbbb       |
| 3 | 345678     | zzzzz       | ccccc       |
| 5 | 567890     | vvvvv       | eeeee       |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

If I run my function using one ID, my function will return a DF with the right values, however, if I try to give it my subset list of IDs, I get ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded.

```
Function123(Subset_Df['Unique ID'],arg1,arg2)
```

Thanks in advance, I can provide specific lines of code if needed.

EDIT:

This is what my base DataFrame looks like:

```
all_players_df.head(6)

+---+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
|   |  PERSON_ID |DISPLAY_LAST.. |TEAM_CITY    |TEAM_CITY    |
+---+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1 | 123456     |Adams, Jordan  | Memphis     | Grizzlies   |
| 2 | 234567     |Anderson, Alan | LA          | Clippers    |
| 3 | 345678     |Ayres, Jeff    | LA          | Clippers    |   
| 4 | 456789     |Aldrich, Cole  | Minnesota   | Timberwolves|
| 5 | 567890     |Albrines,Alex  |Oklahoma City| Thunder     |
| 6 | 678901     |Bass,Brandon   | LA          | Clippers    | 
+---+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I have a subset of those values in a separate DataFrame like so:

```
clippers_players_df.head(3)

+---+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
|   |  PERSON_ID |DISPLAY_LAST.. |TEAM_CITY    |TEAM_CITY    |
+---+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2 | 234567     |Anderson, Alan | LA          | Clippers    |
| 3 | 345678     |Ayres, Jeff    | LA          | Clippers    |   
| 5 | 678901     |Bass,Brandon   | LA          | Clippers    | 
+---+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Then I'll run a function:

```
player_shooting_stats_overall_df(234567,'2015-16','Playoffs')
```

Running this, I'll get the correct returned DF for that function but I want to run the PERSON_ID for the clippers through my function. I'll try:

```
player_shooting_stats_overall_df(clippers_players_df['PERSONID'],'2015-16','Playoffs')
```

but this is where I get the error ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded.

Comment: Please do provide those specific lines of code.

Comment: Thanks. I just edited the post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your function takes scalars as input while you pass in a pandas series (i.e., column of a dataframe). Consider a [pandas.Series.apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) for element-wise operations. For the other positional arguments, use `args` keyword.

```
dfSeries = clippers_players_df['PERSONID'].apply(player_shooting_stats_overall_df, 
                                                 args=('2015-16','Playoffs'))
```

Do note the above will create a series of multiple data frames, assuming a df is the returned value of function. To combine all into single data frame, use `pd.concat()` after converting series to a list:

```
clippersdf = pd.concat(dfSeries.tolist())
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked great. I'll read up more on the apply documentation.